# How to get session values from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

Here is my code

```
class CreateSessionsTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->unique();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity');
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('sessions');
    }
}
```

In `config/session.php` file changed `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),`
In DB table was created. 
When user login i used below code to push values into session

```
Session::put('userid', $userid);
Session::put('useremail', $useremail);
```

Then another method i checked session

```
$data = Session::all();
        var_dump($data);
```

Its returning like this,

```
array (size=3)
  '_token' => string 'kD3zC2YF4v63RF1EkAVe0YoM4zLj9kGtiV4vpEzG' (length=40)
  '_previous' => 
    array (size=1)
      'url' => string 'http://localhost/Login' (length=28)
  'flash' => 
    array (size=2)
      'old' => 
...
```

So how to get that user values from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding

```
Session::save();
```

Its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Which Laravel version are you using? If it's 5.3, try with the following:

```
//Store value
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

//Get value
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'valueIfItsNotReturned');
```

The second argument is the default value that will be returned if the key does not exist in the session.

If it doesn't work, see if you get the same problem by changing the session driver to **file**.

Comment: Im using Laravel 5.1